# ¿Cómo cambiar el value por el nombre del option de una etiqueta select de HTML?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Estoy consumiendo unos servicios y el contenido de ese valor se pinta como viene de la base de datos, como bien se sabe eso ya es productivo y no tengo permisos para hacer lo de la BD. Un ejemplo es: cambiar "DF" a "Ciudad de México" (Este último que solo se pinte en la vista `JSP`) para que me de a entender este es el código:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbbn_mult_web_pub/css/afiNom/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbbn_mult_web_pub/css/afiNom/datosRegistrados.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="XMY2147">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="titulo1" align="left">Llena los siguientes campos:</div>
 <div>
  <nav>
  <h3 align="center">Los datos que quedarán registrados son:</h3>
  <div class="content">

   <form:form commandName="persona">
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey"
     value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
    <div id="contenedor">
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>Nombre:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <!-- <label>Diana Baez Dorantes</label> -->
       <label>${persona.name} ${persona.motherLastName} ${persona.lastName}</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <!-- <label>11-03-1980</label> -->
       <label>${persona.birthDate}</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>Lugar de nacimiento:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <!-- <label>Ciudad de México</label> -->
       <label>${persona.birthPlace}</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>G&eacute;nero:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <!-- <label>Femenino</label> -->
       <label>${persona.sex}</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>CURP:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <!-- <label>BADD110313HCMLNS09</label> -->
       <label>${persona.curp}</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>Correo electr&oacute;nico:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <!-- <label>diana_baez@gmail.com </label> -->
       <label>${persona.email}</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>Teléfono celular:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <!-- <label>5525608650</label> -->
       <label>${persona.telefonoCelular}</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>Fecha de operación:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <label>27-02-2017</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
      <div id="columna1">
       <label>Hora de operación:</label>
      </div>
      <div id="columna2">
       <label>14:00:02</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="candadoStyle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content1">
     <div id="envioCodigo">
      <div id="men_otp_1">
       <p align="center">
        Te hemos enviado un c&oacute;digo a tu celular. Tienes 5 minutos
        para ingresarlo. Al momento de introducir el c&oacute;digo,
        est&aacute;s aceptando que <strong>Bancomer</strong> te haga
        llegar notificaciones al celular que acabas de proporcionar.
       </p>
      </div>

      <div id="txtCodSeguridad" align="center">
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td align="right">Ingresa código de seguridad:</td>
         <td width="330px"><input type="text" id="inputCodSeg"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       <div class="lblReciCod">
        <a>No recibí codigo de seguridad</a>
        <!-- <label class="lblReciCod">No recibí codigo de seguridad</label> -->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
     <input class="styleBotonCancel send" type="submit"
      name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancelar"> <input
      class="styleBotonConfirm send" type="submit" name="_eventId_fin"
      value="Confirmar">
    </div>
   </form:form>
  </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Prácticamente lo que requiere es cambiar dichos valores, es decir que se pinte en el `JSP`. Espero y me puedan proporcionar algún ejemplo para así poder guiarme.

Answer (score 0):

Usa Javascript. Todos los navegadores modernos soportan Javascript, es un MUST HAVE.

```
<script> /*código Javascript*/ </script>
```

Es indispensable que dispongas del valor que quieres escribir. Para ello lo necesitarás obtener de la base de datos, a través del servicio que consumes, claro.

Recuerda esto: JAVA se ejecuta en el SERVIDOR.
JAVASCRIPT se ejecuta en el NAVEGADOR.

La página HTML se compila y regenera en el Servidor y el código Java genera código HTML. Es aquí donde obtienes tu objeto y debes acceder a él mediante Javascript (esto se hará en el navegador):

```
${objeto.atributo}
```

Tendrás que hacer un:

```
var option = document.getElementById("idOption");
var name = option.getAttribute("name");
option.setAttribute("value", name);
```

Asegúrate de usar una buena codificación para mostrar los valores y debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta, estuve intentando realizar con Java pero no tuve exito, el detalle que no sé mucho de JavaScript, habria manera en que me puedas explicar el codigo que me proporcionas? El detalle es que solo requiriria dependiendo el usuario en donde seleccione en este solo cambiaria en esta expresion: <label>${persona.birthPlace}</label> puede ser cualquiera en este caso, DF tendria que cambiar a "Ciudad de Mexico" o GR= Guerrero ya que asi es como vienen en la BD

Comment: Hola @ÓscarFerrerJoyera, Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta